# Probability got at least R in a 6-sided die at least X out of Y rolls and the expected return

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on calculating the probability that I got at least R in a 6-die at in at least X out of Y rolls.

I tried complement to solve this with R = 5, X = 2 and Y = 3

1. Probability that no 5 or 6 will be rolled in 3 rolls: $({\frac{4}{6}})^3$
2. Probability that a 5 or 6 is rolled in the first rolls and not appear in the two next rolls: $({\frac{2}{6}}) * ({\frac{4}{6}})^2$ . Count possiblities that each of the 3 die could be 5 or 6 and the rest not: ${\binom{3}{2}}$.

Total it would be: 1 -  $({\frac{4}{6}})^3$ - $({\frac{2}{6}}) * ({\frac{4}{6}})^2$ * ${\binom{3}{2}}$.

Is my solution correct? And how would it be generalized?

And how do I count the expected return from this given that if I do gambling and  actually got $\geq$ 5 at least 2 out of 3 rolls, I would be paid W = 3 times the amount of what I bet?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about your approach, although I might be misunderstanding.  For instance ${6}\choose{4}$ is 15 which can't be a probability (and the cube of course is even larger).  It seems like your problem can be thought about, generally, in terms of a Binomial distribution.  Each roll is a trial, the success probability is what ever the probability of getting at least R in one roll is, and then you have the number of successful trials.  I believe if you use the cumulative distribution function (borrowing from Wikipedia-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

$F(k;n,p) = \Pr(X \le k) = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k \rfloor} {n\choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$
where $\lfloor k\rfloor$ is the "floor" under ''k'', i.e. the greatest integer less than or equal to ''k'',

you can apply this to your problem - I believe you'll need to subtract this from 1 to get the "at least X out of Y rolls" part of your problem or some adjustment like that.  I hope this helps.

Comment: My bad. I mean ${\frac{4}{6}}$. I’m sorry